# Absolute DIV inside dojo Dialog

Tags: html, css, dialog, dojo

I have created a dialog and inside it I have put a Multi-select Combo box control. A list of options pops out when a user clicks the dropdown button. The problem is that, the list is bigger than the dialog so half of the list hides behind the dialog. This list uses a DIV with absolute positioning and when it reaches the border of dialog then rest of the list hides. I want it to be shown fully.

See the below image:

[image]

I have tried z-Index and opacity property to get the list div above dialog, but it does not work.

Comment: I added css and html tags.  I think that makes sense and will help get more people to look at the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the Dojo dialog has the following CSS attribute: `overflow: hidden` which means that any content that's going outside the box of that DIV, will become invisible (like the example in your image).

The CSS code causing this is:

```
.dijitDialog {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

You can probably overrride this (by setting a new `overflow` type), but it might break the dialog itself, so you should be cautious. To know what values are possible, look at [this link](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflow.html) for more information about the CSS.